# How to insert array contenent in multiple rows PHP

Tags: php, arrays

in my dynamic table where the user adds or removes rows, using the save button, sending to a class an arrays. These vectors correspond to the contents removed from the cells.

A small example of how they are structured:

```
    input1.name = "product[]";

    input2.name = "seller[]";

    input3.name = "description[]"

    ... etc.
```

Here we have the code to distribute the products of several lines. I want to make sure that in my table within the database to be created (for example: if you put two products is to say 2 rows in the table in the database).

Product 1: first table row of the database 
Product 2: second table row of the database

You can do that? In the code that I am attaching below I have trouble doing this in the loop foreach, I should do an insert with a query within each cycle but I've never worked this way.

This is the code in the class:

```
public function execute_Insert()
{
    if (isset($_POST['sending']))
    {
        if ($_POST['sending'] == "save")
        {
            foreach($_POST['product'] as $key => $value)
            {
                $product = $_POST['product'];
                print "product key=$key value=$value<br/>";

                foreach($_POST['seller'] as $key => $value)
                {
                    $seller = $_POST['seller'];
                    print "seller key=$key value=$value<br/>";

                    foreach($_POST['description'] as $key => $value) 
                    {
                        $description = $_POST['description'];
                        print "description key=$key value=$value<br/>";

                        foreach($_POST['quantity'] as $key => $value) 
                        {
                            $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
                            print "quantity key=$key value=$value<br/>";

                            foreach($_POST['priece'] as $key => $value)
                            {
                            $priece = $_POST['priece'];
                            print "priece key=$key value=$value<br/>";

                            } 
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand you correctly but this is how I should do it, if I'm right:

```
$prod = htmlentities($_POST['product']); // this is an array
$seller = htmlentities($_POST['seller']);
// then do foreach
foreach ($prod as $p) {
    // do the insert in sql
}
foreach ($seller as $s) {
    // do the insert in sql
}
```

Comment: what kind of query should I run in the foreach? 
The value must be entered in the corresponding cell

Comment: you mean the sql statement, the insert statement?

Comment: Yes, I want to know how to insert the contents of the multiple rows in my database table.
For example, if the user has entered in the cells of these values ​​in html table product:
Harddisk - (First row of the table), bulb (second row of the table).
The array product will consist of: "hardisk", "bulb".
These two values ​​must be sent in a query to the database table, but must be part of two different lines, so I have two lines with different products.

Comment: what have you tried so far? in sql transactions, use PDO, http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: I tried with this: 
product='".mysql_real_escape_string($this->product)."',
but the array is placed on a line for all products.

Can you help me? I can't solve the problem